# The initial process creates 5 child processes, and waits for them to finish. Each child process performs 5 repetitions, where in each repetition

Tags: c, process

I'm a bit confused with the creation of processes with `fork()`, `sleep()` and `wait()` in c. Take the following piece of code:

```
       #include <stdio.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>
    
     void childProcess(void);
    
     void childProcess(void)
     {
       for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
       {
         printf("pid: %d email: myemail\n", getpid());
         sleep(1);
       }
     }
    
     int main(int argc, char *argv[])
     {
       for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
       {
         pid_t childpid;
    
         if ((childpid = fork()) == 0)
         {
    
          childProcess();
          exit(0);
         }
       }
     
    
     int status;
     while (wait(&status) > 0)
     {
     }
    
     return 0;
    }
```

After this piece of code has been executed,executes processes but does not remove repetitions from 5 processes. I'm a little confused with the process.

The initial process creates 5 child processes, and waits for them to finish.
Each child process performs 5 repetitions, where in each repetition:

Prints the message
pid: PID email: USER_EMAIL
where PID is the child PID of the process, while USER_EMAIL is the email

Suspends its operation for 1 second (at a time) with the sleep call

The parent process prints the children's PIDs when they are finished

P.S I EDIT THE CODE

Comment: The loop that waits for all the processes should be outside the loop.

Comment: What does "does not remove repetitions" mean? Please give the exact expected result vs actual result. For starters you need to move the `wait` loop to be outside the outer `for` block.

Comment: @Barmar I had tried it but it runs to infinity.

Comment: Why do you have a loop printing the PID? It's going to print the same thing 5 times.

Comment: Please edit the question to explain what this is supposed to do. It looks like you tried to put it all in the title.

Comment: @mixalispetros , don't say you tried something that's not in the question.  Update your code.  Make sure to use the triple-backticks "```" to delineate the code, not the leading spaces - that's tricky to get right. Use a code formatter like https://codebeautify.org/c-formatter-beautifier so indentation mistakes are clear when posting.  And welcome to SO.

Comment: You still have not clearly told us what the current behaviour of the code is and how it is not what is expected.

Comment: @Barmar i edit the question and sry i am new here.

Comment: If the parent process should print the child's PID when it exits, it needs to assign the result of `wait()` to a variable.

Comment: Your loop that calls `wait()` is in the child process. It never executes because the child calls `exit(0)` before that.

Comment: Τhe current behavior of the code is that when I take the wait loop out of if it runs indefinitely while when I leave it as it is above it prints 1 or 2 or sometimes while I want the following. The initial process creates 5 child processes, and waits for them to finish.
Each child process performs 5 repetitions, where in each repetition:
Prints the message
pid: PID email: USER_EMAIL

Suspends its operation for 1 second (at a time) with the sleep call
The parent process prints the children's PIDs when they are finished

Comment: @Barmar  I have the same problem I described above without exit (0);

Comment: Thank you for devoting some of your precious time to explaining to me, if you could devote a little more to me I would be very grateful

Comment: @barmar If I take the wait loop out of for there is a way to stop all the processes together instead of running 5 processes and stop them one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mixalispetros, you have multiple things to fix, and they all have to be fixed together for your code to work as intended.

```
      exit(0);

      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        wait(NULL);
      }
```

The process ends on `exit(0)`.   `wait` is never called.

```
    if (fork() == 0) {
         // what code runs here?  The code in the new process
    }
```

What code runs within the `fork()` conditional?  The *new* process's code.  Which process should run `wait()`?  The *original* process.  So in addition to being after an `exit`, the `wait()` is also in the wrong process.

Where to move it?  The `for` loop `wait()`s for 5 child processes.  Why would there be 5 child processes for which to to `wait()`?  Because we had already started *all 5* child processes *before* we went into our loop of 5 `wait()`s.

The `wait()`s must happen not just outside the *child process* conditional block, but also outside the loop around the call to `fork()`.

> I'm a bit confused with the creation of processes with fork(), sleep() and wait() in c

It *is* confusing.  Refer to the documentation often to keep it straight.
Remember, [`fork()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) returns twice - in the *original* process (returning the process ID of the new process), and in the *new* process (returning `0`).  [`wait()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html), will wait for the next child process to exit.

In summary, put the `wait` loop *outside* the loop that `fork()`s child processes.  This will also move it ouside the block of code that executes in the `child` process.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main() {
  // this loop creates 5 processes
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (fork() == 0) {
      printf("Child %d, PID %d\n", i, getpid());
      sleep(i);
      exit(0);
    }
  }
  // now, all subprocesses were started

  // wait for the same number of child processes to end
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    wait(NULL);
  }
}
```

Comment: I did what you told me but at -1 I get an error as opposed to the 0 that runs, but I have a question. When I run it it runs the 5 processes and stops them one by one, can I somehow stop them all together?

Comment: I lost you unfortunately and got a little confused, I still have work to do to improve, sorry I got a little annoying

Comment: "can I somehow stop them all together" Who is stopping the processes?  The child processes `exit` of their own accord.  the parent simply `wait()`s for notification.  Can you explain exactly what you mean by "stop them all at once?"

Comment: I want to say that when I run it for example it comes out as output:
pid01
pid02
pid03
pid04
pido05
05
pid06
pid07
pid08
pid09
pid10
10Can this be done without running all the processes? Stop them all together?I may not be clear,  forgive me

Comment: You're right by the way, I was wrong about `wait()`. It *does* take a pointer and `NULL` is therefore correct.

Comment: Did you understand the previous one I wrote to you or did I not become clear in the end?

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand what you mean "without running all the processes" and "stop them all together".  In your code, you're waiting for the processes to complete.  This  way the child processes finish processing and then the parent completes.

Comment: I edited the code, I would like your opinion if I really understood well and I run it correctly. Thank you for devoting some of your precious time, I appreciate it very much.

Comment: You're still `wait`ing 5 times for every process you `fork()`.   Take a close look at my answer.  You need to move that `wait` loop not just outside the `if`, but also outside the `fork()` loop entirely

Comment: I'm trying to understand and this outside the fork confuses me, I take it out of the if so it's not really outside the fork? or is it meant to take it out of the for?

Comment: by "`fork()` loop I mean the loop that `fork()`s 5 times.  `if` does not loop.   Think through why this needs to be the case: "Why would there be 5 child processes for which to to wait()? Because we had already started all 5 child processes before we went into our loop of 5 wait()s."  We need to start *all* the processes before we start waiting, if we want them all to run concurrently

Comment: I really feel so stupid that I can not understand it, would it be possible to show me please?

Comment: i edited the code. in this way?

Comment: It's natural to not understand something until you figure it out.  That's why I'm trying to lead you to your answer instead of just handing it to you.  Keep thinking through what's happening in your code.  Think about the order of operations.  You want to start *all 5* processes.  Then, once *all 5* processes are started, you want to wait for *once `for` each of the 5* processes.

Comment: i edit again the code , you can tell me now if i understand how to do it?

Comment: You ahouldn't edit the question to match the answer. Now no one can see the original problems that the answer is referring to. @mixalispetros

Comment: @DanielFarrell After explain all the problems, you should post the corrected code so he can see how it all fits together.

Comment: @mixalispetros see example code.  See how the `for` loop that `wait()`s is *not* inside the `for` loop that `fork()`s.

Comment: @DanielFarrell i edit the code. You can see now if i am right?